# Rethinkdb: Conflict strategy for different keys in document

Tags: rethinkdb

I have documents similar to this

```
{id: 0, a: [0, 1], b: null, c: 4, d: 6, e: 7}
{id: 0, a: [1,2], b: 3, c: 5, d: null, f:8}
```

I am wanting to batch insert documents so that `a` is added to the array as a set, null values are overwritten but other values stay as is. So the resulting document in the table would be

```
{id:0, a:[0,1,2], b:3, c:4, d:6, e:7, f:8}
```

I tried doing the following in the data explorer but am getting the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token return`

```
r.table('foo').insert(
 [{id: 0, a: [0, 1], b: null, c: 4, d: 6}, {id: 0, a: [1,2], b: 3, c: 5, d: null}],
  {
    conflict: function(id, old_doc, new_doc){
      return (new_doc.keys().map(function (key) {
        return r.branch(key.eq('a'), 
          [key, old_doc('a').setUnion(new_doc('a'))],
          r.branch(old_doc(key).eq(null),
            [key, new_doc(key)],
            [key, old_doc(key)])
        )
      })).coerceTo('object')
    }
  })
```

I also thought about using merge for this case but would need to be able to define a conflict strategy for identical keys and it doesn't seem like you can do that at this point [issue #873](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/873).

EDIT:
The function I ended up using after [@mlucy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38949688/6406065) answer and some other changes.

```
r.table('foo').insert(
 [{id: 0, a: [0, 1], b: null, c: 4, d: 6, e: 7}, {id: 0, a: [1,2], b: 3, c: 5, d: null, f:8}],
  {
    conflict: function(id, old_doc, new_doc){
      return (new_doc.keys().setUnion(old_doc.keys()).map(function (key) {
        return r.branch(old_doc.hasFields(key).and(new_doc.hasFields(key).not()),
          [key, old_doc(key)],
          new_doc.hasFields(key).and(old_doc.hasFields(key).not()),
          [key, new_doc(key)],
          r.branch(key.eq('a'), 
            [key, old_doc('a').setUnion(new_doc('a'))],
            r.branch(old_doc(key).eq(null).and(new_doc(key).eq(null).not()),
              [key, new_doc(key)],
              [key, old_doc(key)])
          )
        )
      })).coerceTo('object')
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return in `return r.branch(old_doc(key).eq(null),` shouldn't be there, which is why you're getting that error.  You also need `key.eq(a)` to be `key.eq('a')`, and `set_union` should be `setUnion`.  Finally, I think you should be calling `FOO.coerceTo('object')` rather than `r.object(FOO)` there.